# How to show location structure in separate columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have the following `Location` table

```
ID  Name       ParentID
-----------------------
1   TopLevel   NULL
2   Region 1   1
3   Fleet 1    2
4   Fleet 2    2
```

I have just recently finished up writing a recursive CTE to display this structure in a hierarchy approach:

```
TopLevel
-Region 1
--Fleet 1
--Fleet 2
```

I now need to write a query to return this structure in a column hierarchal format:

```
Level1     Level2   Level3  Level4  Level5  Level6
Top Level
Top Level  Region 1 Fleet 1
Top Level  REgion 1 Fleet 2
```

The maximum levels deep a location can go is 9. How would I accomplish this? I was trying to use the recursive CTE and build on that, but I don't think that is going to work. Any other ideas?

Comment: You should be doing this on the application side.

Comment: There is no front end to this, it's all in the DB.

Comment: How is it "all in the DB"? All of the end users who care about rows vs. columns are viewing the results in Management Studio?

Comment: The levels are used in a procedure which is used by another usp to do work, then it is pushed out to a report. The report I suppose would be the front end, but the levels if possible need to be taken care of in the DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here would be one method to accomplish the output, using a recursive CTE hard-coded to fill out up to 9 levels worth of hierarchy (you would need to change table/column references as necessary to your real object names, and you may need to increase `varchar(50)` if the actual type of `name` column is wider than that):

```
with cte as (
  select id, 1 as level,
    name as level1,
    cast(null as varchar(50)) as level2,
    cast(null as varchar(50)) as level3,
    cast(null as varchar(50)) as level4,
    cast(null as varchar(50)) as level5,
    cast(null as varchar(50)) as level6,
    cast(null as varchar(50)) as level7,
    cast(null as varchar(50)) as level8,
    cast(null as varchar(50)) as level9
  from table1 t
  where parentid is null

  union all

  select t.id, cte.level + 1 as level,
    case when level = 0 then t.name else cte.level1 end as level1,
    case when level = 1 then t.name else cte.level2 end as level2,
    case when level = 2 then t.name else cte.level3 end as level3,
    case when level = 3 then t.name else cte.level4 end as level4,
    case when level = 4 then t.name else cte.level5 end as level5,
    case when level = 5 then t.name else cte.level6 end as level6,
    case when level = 6 then t.name else cte.level7 end as level7,
    case when level = 7 then t.name else cte.level8 end as level8,
    case when level = 8 then t.name else cte.level9 end as level9
  from table1 t
  inner join cte on cte.id = t.parentid
)
select * from cte;
```

Sample Output:

```
| ID | LEVEL |   LEVEL1 |   LEVEL2 |  LEVEL3 | LEVEL4 | LEVEL5 | LEVEL6 | LEVEL7 | LEVEL8 | LEVEL9 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1 |     1 | TopLevel |   (null) |  (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |
|  2 |     2 | TopLevel | Region 1 |  (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |
|  3 |     3 | TopLevel | Region 1 | Fleet 1 | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |
|  4 |     3 | TopLevel | Region 1 | Fleet 2 | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |
```

Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0bd5d/14

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I was doing everything identical, but the ELSE in the case statements was what I was missing, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I could see using 9 UNION statements so you might get your desired output, but it wouldn't be pretty.

Here goes with 3 levels (you should be able to add on accordingly):

```
SELECT Name as Level1, '' as Level2, '' as Level3
FROM Location
WHERE ParentId IS NULL
UNION
SELECT L1.Name as Level1, L2.Name as Level2, '' as Level3
FROM Location L1
JOIN Location L2 
    ON L1.Id = L2.ParentId 
    AND L1.ParentId IS NULL
UNION
SELECT L1.Name as Level1, L2.Name as Level2, L3.Name as Level3
FROM Location L1
JOIN Location L2 
    ON L1.Id = L2.ParentId 
    AND L1.ParentId IS NULL
JOIN Location L3 
    ON L2.Id = L3.ParentId 
    AND L1.ParentId IS NULL
```

And so on and so forth adding more tables to Joins for each subsequent level.  Seems like there might be a better/easier way, just the only I could think of off the top of my head.

Here's the [Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a33b1/1).